# Python turning list into a useable params for post request

Tags: python

I have a list of urls:

```
images=['https://example.co/123','https://example.co/124',...]
```

I need to create another list like so:

```
files=[('images',requests.get(image).content),('images',requests.get(image).content),..]
```

I need a list of `('images',requests.get(image).content)` for each image url in images list. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for list comprehensions.

```
images=['https://example.co/123','https://example.co/124', ...]
files = [('images', requests.get(image).content) for image in images]
```

Comment: Awesome. I never thought it would be that simple. Thanks. I'll accept the answer when it allows me to.

Comment: @MatthewSemik that tends to be why I like Python. "I never thought it would be that simple" is the reaction to figuring out the proper solution to almost any syntactical conundrum